# Pass variable name in formula in a cell in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to count number of cells containing string `RESULT` in `Sheet1` and put the count result in `Sheet2`, if some particular string matches in cell of `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

I tried this using the below logic:

```
lnCol =20
lastRow = 10
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastRow + 2, 6).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!" & Range(Cells(21, lnCol), Cells(800, lnCol)).Address(False, False) & ", ""RESULT"",'Sheet1'!" & Range(Cells(21, lnCol), Cells(800, lnCol)).Address(False, False) & ,""*""&Sheet2!.Cells(lastRow + 2, 5)&""*"")"
```

But the formula cannot recognize the variable name and puts it as it is.

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$T$21:$T$599,"RESULT",Sheet1!$D$21:$D$599,Sheet1!"*"&D3&Sheet1!"*")
```

This is my formula directly written in excel. But I want to convert this to VBA and replace `T` and `D` in the formula with corresponding column numbers
How can I achieve this using VBA?

Comment: You are mixing up some syntax at the end with: `,""*""&Sheet2!.Cells(lastRow + 2, 5)&""*"")"`. First there is a double quote missing, second I think you want to actually refer to a value in a specific cell. You can do that the same you did earlier in the string (with `Address`) or get the name through `VBA`. If the latter then: `",""*""" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lastRow + 2, 5).Value & """*"")"` looks much better, assuming you have `lastrow` somewhere declared.

Comment: Also, did you know you can do this directly in `VBA` instead of inserting a formula first?

Comment: I am new to VBA, I don't know much about it

Comment: Then I guess it would be hard to see through what you wrote. My advise would be to look into [`WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countifs) method. Declare your `Worksheet` variables, some `Range` objects etc. And run the method.

Comment: I would recommend inserting the formula manually in Excel first and then post that formula in your question above. Once you know how your formula should look like, it will be easy to break it up to include variables in it :)

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($T$21:$T$599,"RESULT",$D$21:$D$599,"*"&D3&"*")` This is my formula directly written in excel. But I want to convert this to VBA and replace `T` and `D` in the formula with corresponding column numbers

Comment: HINT: `=COUNTIFS($T$21:$T$599,"RESULT",$D$21:$D$599,"*"&D3&"*")` can be written as `"=COUNTIFS($T$21:$T$599,""RESULT"",$D$21:$D$599,""*""&D3&""*"")"` which can also be written as `"=COUNTIFS($" & "T" & "$21:$" & "T" & "$599,""RESULT"",$" & "D" & "$21:$" & "D" & "$599,""*""&" & "D" & "3&""*"")"` ;)